# ESP32 Websocket JavaScript

Tags: websocket, message, addeventlistener, esp32

Good day,

I've read a lot, but just can't get anywhere.  As I understood it all messages arrive at onmessage ?!  The RandomNumber transmits a speed and sends the data to the client.  Works so far, but now I would like to send another speed signal “Rpm2 = randomNumber2” and a stop signal.
I thought that I would manage the data with if () under ws.onmessage.  But I don't know how to separate the data.  I'm sorry for my ignorance, hope you can help me.

What should I do to separate the data?  I tried different variants with if ().  Do I have to change something with the globalClient-> Text?

Thank you and best regards.

````
float rpm = 123;
float rpm2 = 12;

AsyncWebServer server(80);
AsyncWebsocketClient * globalClient = NULL;

Void onWsEvent(AsyncWebSocket * server, AsyncWebsocketClient * client, AwsEventType type, void * arg, uint8_t *data, size_t len){

if(type == WS_EVT_CONNECT){
globalClient = client;
}
else if(type == WS_EVT_DISCONNECT){
globalClient = NULL;
}
}

Void SendRpm() {
if(globalClient != NULL && globalClient->status() == WS_CONNECTED) {
if(rpm > 10) {
String randomNumber = String(rpm);
globalClient->text(randomNumber);
}
if(rpm2 > 10) {
String randomNumber2 = String(rpm2);
globalClient->text(randomNumber2);
}
}
}

Client side:

var ws = new Websocket(“ws://……./ws”);

ws.onopen = function() {
console.log(“Connected”);
};

ws.onclose = function() {
console.log(“Disconnected”);
};

ws.onopen = function() {
console.log(“Connected”);
};

ws.addEventListener(“message“, function (evt) { 
console.log(“Received: “ + evt.data);

if(typeof (evt.data) !== “randomNumber“) { document.getElementById(“rpm1value”).value = evt.data;
}
if(typeof (evt.data) !== “randomNumber2“) { document.getElementById(“rpm2value”).value = evt.data;
}
}); ` ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Can be closed.  I switched to Arduinojson.  Anyway, thank you and all the best.
My solution:

````
float m1rpm = 123;
float m2rpm = 12;

AsyncWebServer server(80);
AsyncWebSocket ws(“/ws”);

AsyncWebsocketClient * globalClient = NULL;

Void onWsEvent(AsyncWebSocket * server, AsyncWebsocketClient * client, AwsEventType type, void * arg, uint8_t *data, size_t len){

if(type == WS_EVT_CONNECT){
globalClient = client;
}
else if(type == WS_EVT_DISCONNECT){
globalClient = NULL;
}
}

Void SendRpm() {
StaticJsonDocument<200> json;
json[“rpmstatus”] = m1rpm;
json[“rpmstatus2”] = m2rpm;

char buffer[100];
serializeJson(json, buffer);

if(globalClient != NULL && globalClient->status() == WS_CONNECTED) {
globalClient->text(buffer);
}
}

Client side: js 

var ws = new Websocket(“ws://……./ws”);

ws.onopen = function() {
console.log(“Connected”);
};

ws.onclose = function() {
console.log(“Disconnected”);
};

ws.onopen = function() {
console.log(“Connected”);
};

ws.addEventListener(“message“, function (evt) { 
buffer = JSON.parse(evt.data);
document.getElementById(“rpm1”).value = buffer.rpmstatus;
document.getElementById(“rpm2”).value = buffer.rpmstatus2;
});

HTML:

<progress id=“rpm1” max=“500” value=“0”></progress>
<progress id=“rpm2” max=“500” value=“0”></progress> ```
````